# Authorization adapter &quot;actions&quot; was not found. CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization

I use the CakePHP Auth componenet in my web site. The code works fine in windows but after uploading it to linux online host, it give the message
Authorization adapter "actions" was not found. CakePHP

Any idea regarding the problem ?

```
      <?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');


    class AppController extends Controller {

          public  $mobile;
        public $components = array(
            'Acl',
            'Auth' => array(
                'authorize' => array(
                    'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers/'),
                ),
            ),
            'Session',
            'RequestHandler',
        );
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Js' => array('Jquery'));


        public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
   // print_r($this->request); die;

   if ($this->request->is('post') && isset($this->request['data']['access_token'])) {

            App::uses('User', 'Model');
            $this->User = new User();



               // print_r($this->request['data']['access_token']);die;
                $this->mobile = $this->User->authenticateMobile($this->request['data']['access_token']);


            }



//        print_r('APPCONT');
//        print_r($this->request);
//        die;
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'User'),
            //'ChangeEg',
            'Form' 
        );



        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions';

        $this->Auth->loginError = "Wrong credentials";
        $this->Auth->authError = "This part of the website is protected.";

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'feedbacks', 'action' => 'add');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index');


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I had de same problem, was a CamelCased mistake,

instead write $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';

i wrote $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller'.

In windows works ok, but in Linux not.

see this post https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cake-php/wZGFoJ4ayx0